# how to compile chromiumous version of bsdiff for android

Tags: android-ndk, bsdiff

I am compiling the chromiumous version of bsdiff for use on Android. When compiling the so file through ndk-build, it will prompt that the fopencookie function cannot be found. I am a newbie in C language. I checked that fopencookie is a non-standard function. There should be no such function in the environment provided by ndk. In this case, what should I do? Write a fopencookie function yourself? , Is there any other way, thank you all!

code:
https://github.com/854133055/BsdiffChromiumous

env:
ndk-build --version
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for x86_64-apple-darwin

Answer (score 0):

merge the changes from chromium into bsdiff.
https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=409664